# Building Shiny app with Flickity carousel

Tags: r, shiny

I am building an app in Shiny and would like to interface it with metafizzy's [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) carousel. On a single page app flickity works well using the initializing code in the example below.

However, the app I am creating uses a navbar. It seems that when I initialize the carousel it works well on the first tab, but carousels on the second tab (or other) will not initialize. However, if you are on Tab 2 (for example) and resize the window, the carousel seems to initialize and all runs smoothly on that Tab, but this will turn off / hide the other carousels on the other tabs.

I am wondering if there is a way to change the script so that all carousels on all tabs will be initialized and available when the page loads? I am very new to javascript so apologies if this is a simple question.

Thank you

ui:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(tagList(

  tags$head(
    includeCSS("www/flickity-docs.css"),
    includeCSS("www/styles.css"),
    includeScript("www/flickity-docs.min.js")
  ),           

  navbarPage(' ',
             position = ('fixed-top'), 
             collapsible = T, 


             # Panel 1 =====================================================

             tabPanel('Page 1',

                      div(class = "main-carousel",

                          div(class = "carousel-cell", 
                              div(class = "carousel-inner", 
                                  h2('This text on page 1.1 is appearing')
                              )
                          )

                      )

             ), 


             # Panel 2 =====================================================

             tabPanel('Page 2',

                      div(class = "main-carousel",

                          div(class = "carousel-cell", 
                              div(class = "carousel-inner", 
                                  h2('This text on page 2.1 is not appearing')
                              )
                          )

                      )

             )

  ),

  HTML(
    "<script type='text/javascript'>

    // selectorAll for multiple flickity
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.main-carousel');

    // loop to initialize
    for ( var i=0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var elem = elems[i]
    new Flickity( elem, {

    // options
    cellAlign: 'center',
    wrapAround: true,
    cellSelector: '.carousel-cell', 
    });
    }
    </script>"
  )


)
)
```

server (blank for now):

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;         
  height: 100px;        
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0%;
  line-height:0px;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}

.carousel-cell:before {
  content: normal;
}

.carousel-inner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  content: normal;
  padding-right: 12.5%;
  padding-left: 12.5%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size:20px;
}
```